# Proving an optimal solution does not exist for a linear program

Tags: solution-verification, linear-programming

The question is prove there is no optimal solution for a generic linear program.

max ${c^Tx : Ax = b, x\ge 0}$

I'm not sure if this would be enough of a proof to state that but if I did something along the lines of,

let ${\lambda}$ be a parmetre [0,1]. let x' be an optimal solution.
A$({{\lambda}(x')+(1-\lambda)(x'))} = b$

If I take some negative vector ${-y^T}$, multiple it by both sides and get
${-y^TA({{\lambda}x'+(1-\lambda)x')= -y^tb}}$ to get a positive left hand side and a negative right hand side would that suffice to claim that there is no optimal solution. Would that just state there is no feasible solution rather than no optimal solution? Would proving that it is unbounded work instead?

sorry if I used the wrong tags, this is my first time using StackExchange.

Answer (score 1):

You need more conditions on $A,b,c$ otherwise just a program can have an optimal solution. For example if $A = I$ and $b \ge 0$. Then for all $c$ the program has an optimal solution.

Comment: How would I go about that? Would restricting the set of all possible solutions to only convex solutions be enough conditions or do I need to apply conditions to A, b, c seperatly?

Comment: What is a convex solution?

Comment: that the set of optimal solutions are complex